# Can I load a package's data set without installing the package?

Tags: r

In package [*ISLR*](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ISLR/ISLR.pdf), there is a data set called `Default`.

I want to use that data set, but the *ISLR* package is not installed on my machine.

```
data(Default)
# Warning message:
# In data(Default) : data set ‘Default’ not found
library(ISLR)
# Error in library(ISLR) : there is no package called ‘ISLR’
```

Since I'll probably never use it again, I don't want to install the package.  I thought about reading it from the web, but it's not in the [linked web page](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/data.html) from the package description.

In general, is there a way to load a data set from a package without installing the package?

Comment: You could download the tar and read it from there - but doubt that is any better for you than installing the package.

Comment: `install.packages("ISLR",dependencies=FALSE); library(ISLR); data(Default); remove.packages("ISLR");` - I know this technically installs the package, but you're going to have to download it one way or another anyway.

Comment: The largest contributed package is currently 60MB and most are under 3MB. Unless you're on a particularly crud connection or CPU, it's not going to take long. And you're probably going to have to download the entire compressed package anyway. So why not keep it simple?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this from within R:

```
download.file("http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/ISLR_1.0.tar.gz",
                dest="ISLR.tar.gz")
untar("ISLR.tar.gz",files="ISLR/data/Default.rda")
L <- load("ISLR/data/Default.rda")
summary(Default)
```

If you want to keep a copy of the data file:

```
file.copy("ISLR/data/Default.rda",".")
```

Clean up:

```
unlink(c("ISLR.tar.gz","ISLR"),recursive=TRUE)
```

I'm not sure you can get around having to download the tarball -- in principle you *might* be able to run `untar()` directly on a network connection, but I don't think the underlying machinery can actually extract a file without downloading the whole tarball to *somewhere* on your machine first.

Answer (score 0):

You said, "Since I'll probably never use it again, I don't want to install the package." If the fact that you'll never use it again is your main concern, then perhaps this solution is not quite what you want, but it is probably the **simplest** solution:

- Install the package with `install.packages()`.
- Extract and save the dataset that you want.
- Uninstall the package with `remove.packages()`.

So the final result is what you want in three simple steps, though the process does involve installing the package, which you hoped to avoid. But you end up without the package in your system that you don't want, so the end result is the same as what you want.